# Regex extract strings

Tags: python, regex, replace

Original text: `This is the first variable "${abc}" and this is the second variable "${def}"`

Desired output: `This is the first variable and this is the second variable`

I want to get rid of `"${abc}"` and `"${def}"` using regex. Currently, I am using this regex command: `\".*\"`  but the output I am getting is `"${abc}" and this is the second variable "${def}"`

Comment: The dup isn't really the same. OP wants to replace text and implement a sort of templating.

Answer (score 0):

You want to match all characters **that are not `"`**, so instead of `.*` do `[^"]*`.

```
>>> in_str = 'This is the first variable "${abc}" and this is the second variable "${def}"'

>>> re.sub(r'"[^"]*"', '', in_str)
'This is the first variable  and this is the second variable '
```

Better yet, constrain it more so you only match `"${...}"`, and not anything enclosed in quotes (`r'"\$\{[^}]*\}"'`)

```
>>> re.sub(r'"\$\{[^}]*\}"', '', in_str)
'This is the first variable  and this is the second variable '
```

Explanation:

```
"\$\{[^}]*\}"
-------------
"           "   : Quotes
 \$             : A literal $ sign
   \{     \}    : Braces
     [^}]*      : Zero or more characters that are not }
```

To get rid of the trailing spaces after the match, add an optional `\s?` at the end of the regex.

```
>>> re.sub(r'"\$\{[^}]*\}"\s?', '', in_str)
'This is the first variable and this is the second variable '
```

Of course, this leaves behind a trailing space if the last word was a match, but you can just `.strip()` that out.

[Try it on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/B5HEaT/1)